# 'No network' Toast not displayed in onCreate

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, handler, toast

Hello everyone i hope you can help.

I've built an RSS reader which populates a ListView. I want to check the user has network access on app start up, if there is no network then the user should see the setEmptyView View and a toast.

In onCreate I've set the list adapter with an empty list so I'm expecting to see the empty view. Then i query the network state and if no network i create a toast. BUT I never see the empty view on start-up and i never see the toast when i don't have a network. Whats going on?

```
public class XMLActivity extends ListActivity {

private List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
private RssListAdapter adapter;
private ListView lv;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//SET LAYOUT WITH EMPTY LIST VIEW 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
    lv = getListView();               //get view layout
    lv.setEmptyView(empty);                   //set empty view
    adapter = new RssListAdapter(this,jobs);  //jobs is empty array list
    setListAdapter(adapter);

//CHECK FOR NETWORK AND DISPLAY TOAST
    try{
        boolean network = RssReader.isOnline(this); //check network state
        if (!network){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(XMLActivity.this, "No Network Access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(XMLActivity.this, "No Network Access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
    }

// START RSS READER HANDLER
    try {
        jobs = RssReader.getLatestRssFeed();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
 //REFRESH ADAPTER FOR LISTVIEW
    adapter.clear();
    for(JSONObject job :jobs){
        adapter.add(job);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             lv.setClickable(true);
```

Why can't i see the empty view or toast, this problem only happens for the onCreate routine. Later toasts and empty views are displayed fine on menu item select so it seems to be a problem specific to the onCreate sequence.

Comment: where do you create the toast object?

Comment: use Toast.makeText(this, "No Network", 3000).show();

Comment: Code updated with new Toast method but still doesn't show the toast.

Comment: Code updated with new Toast method but still doesn't show the toast. It seems like the view isn't initalised, when i have no network i just get a black screen but my empty view is white.

Comment: I added some logging code to try and narrow this down a bit. It shows that during no network the correct toast code is run, however i don't see any toast. I've discovered that actualy i only ever see a toast if it is called after notifydatasetchanged() i.e. when the list view is not empty. Why?? why is my empty view not displaying at this point??

Answer (score 0):

try `Toast.makeToast(this, "msg to user", Toast.TOAST_MSG_SHORT).show();` i'm sure i have a typo in there as i  don't have my devopment machine up and running (yet).

Comment: use Toast.LENGTH_LONG or Toast.LENGTH_SHORT as constant of duration

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
Toast.makeText(XMLActivity.this , "No Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: if you don't get any toast, try to debug and add soe Logs in your code to verify if your programm detect if the network is online or not ,

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!network){    
  Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
  toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  TextView txt1 =  new TextView(this);
  txt1.setText("No Network");
  toast.setView(txt1);
  toast.show();
}
else ...
```

Try this..,,.

Answer (score 0):

You have one condition not covered - what happens if `network` == `true`?

```
 try{
        boolean network = RssReader.isOnline(this); //check network state
        if (!network){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(XMLActivity.this, "No Network Access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(XMLActivity.this, "Network Access!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(XMLActivity.this, "No Network Access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
    }
```